# Run-time error 91 using Worksheet_SelectionChange

Tags: excel, select, event-handling, runtime-error

Does the SelectionChange event have any limitations to selecting ranges? I'm getting a runtime error doing a simple range selection after I select on a cell under the 1st row "Search" header.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim shelvesSht As Worksheet
    Set shelvesSht = ActiveSheet
    Dim selectionRange As Range
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(1, ActiveCell.Column).Value = "Search" Then 
        Dim headerRow As Long
        headerRow = 1
        selectionRange = shelvesSht.Cells(1, 1)  '<--- Here is where I get the error
        MsgBox "Selected cell in Click Col... Moving on"
    End If
End Sub
```

My goal after this is to select the whole first row selectionRange.EntireRow.Select then use this selection to find column numbers for assorted headers.

Answer (score 0):

OK I answered my own question and here was the solution. I think the event was creating a loop which was causing the error. Using error handling in this way seemed to resolve all my problems in this project:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim selectionRange As Range
    Dim itypename As String
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(1, ActiveCell.Column).Value = "Search" Then 'ActiveCell.Column = 10 Then
        'MsgBox "Active Sheet / Selected Sheet Name: " & ActiveSheet.Name
        On Error GoTo ErrHandler
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        selectionRange = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range("A1").EntireRow.Select
        selectionRange.Activate
ErrHandler:
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        'MsgBox "Moving Forward"
   
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = Selection.Find(What:="Description", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
            False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then 'when rng <> nothing means found something'
            rng.Activate
            'MsgBox "Desc Column: " & rng.Column
            itypename = ActiveSheet.Cells(Target.Row, rng.Column).Value
            
        Else
            MsgBox "Did not find Description header"
            Exit Sub
        End If
```

Feel free to make a note in the comments if you can clarify this more.

Thanks.